# How to only return one name rather than multiple

Tags: javascript

I have this code at the moment:

```
for (var i = 0; i < secname.length; i++) {
description = secname[i].description
var price = secname.map(function(x){ return x.price_breakdown.display_charges.price; });
var max = Math.max.apply(null, price);
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, price.filter(Number));

$("#tabledirect").prepend("<tr><td><img id='theImg' src='/assets/-logo.png'/></td><td><b>" + description + "</b></td><td><b>Available</b></td><td><b>" + min + "</b></td><td><b>Booking Fee Included</b></td><td><b>" + price +"</b></td><td><b>" + button + "</b></td></tr>");
}
```

So what this is doing at the moment is passing loads of stuff into the table. e.g.

```
Ticket 1 | Min price | Max price
Ticket 1 | Min price | Max price
Ticket 1 | Min price | Max price
Ticket 1 | Min price | Max price

Ticket 2 | Min price | Max price
Ticket 2 | Min price | Max price
Ticket 2 | Min price | Max price
```

However I'd prefer that it was returned more like this into the table

```
Ticket 1 | Min price | Max price
Ticket 2 | Min price | Max price
```

The other issue is that I don't know what the ticket 1 or ticket 2 name is going to be. So I can't just put ticket1 unique

**edit**

Some of the secname looks like this

```
"secnames": {
    "CIRCLE": {
      "price_levels": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
      ],
      "group": "2",
      "masks": {
        "1": 7,
        "2": 1,
        "3": 0,
        "4": 0
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the whole code snippet? This only prints one row

Comment: could you also describe how `secname` looks like?

Comment: I'll post some of the code for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of tickets with names and min/max prices, you could create a new array like this:

```js
var tickets=[
  {"name":"1","min":10,"max":50},
  {"name":"1","min":20,"max":150},
  {"name":"2","min":40,"max":100},
  {"name":"2","min":30,"max":80}
];
var newTickets=[];

for(i = 0; i < tickets.length; ++i){
    var t = tickets[i];
    var nt = newTickets[t.name];
    if(nt === undefined){
        nt = {"name":t.name, "min":Infinity,"max":0};
    }
    nt.max = Math.max(t.max,nt.max);
    nt.min = Math.min(t.min,nt.min);

    newTickets[t.name] = nt;
}

// do something with newTickets
for(i in newTickets){
  console.log(newTickets[i]);
}
```